# Option to mount .iso in Windows 8 missing

Tags: windows-8, mount, iso-image

I just upgraded from Windows 7. I hear that Windows 8 has native mounting. However, when I right-click the `.ISO` file, there is no mount option. I really need to do this, because I got a  message that MagicISO is not compatible with Windows 8.

How do I mount it?

Pop-up menu without option to **Mount**:

[image]

I also hear that there is a mount button in the ribbon, but I can't find that either.

Comment: This exact same issue also happens after upgrading to Windows 10, and the solution is the same.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It doesn't work if the file association of the `.ISO` file is not **Windows Explorer**. Because you upgraded with MagicISO associated, it suppresses the **Mount** buttons.

1. Simply right-click, and select properties in the menu.
2. Under **Opens with**, select **Change** to change the file association:

   [image]
3. Then select Windows Explorer:

   [image]

(if you can't see Windows Explorer, you can find it at `%windir%\explorer.exe`)

Now both methods should work:

[image][image]

Source: [Yahoo answer](http://nz.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120816034737AA3hJx6)

Comment: MagicIso? you mean WinRar? Installing Winrar usually sets the iso file association as shown in the screenshot the OP posted,

Comment: I am the OP. I installed both WinRar and MagicISO.

Comment: @ronalchn - Do you have to select `File Explorer` or `Windows Explorer` you should clarify because your screenshot doesn't match your description.

Comment: you will not have both on your computer. Windows Explorer was renamed File Explorer in Windows 8. The screenshot might be showing Windows Explorer because I upgraded from Windows 7 (and maybe they missed renaming it there).

Comment: A Windows 8 clean install matches your screenshots, so the text should be changed to match to avoid confusion.

Comment: I can confirm that this same solution works on Windows 10.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to access the files inside the .iso file, what I just do is double click it and it will automatically mount it, giving you access to the files inside the .iso. (Might have been a bit redundant on this answer)

Comment: it doesn't work if the file association is wrong, because it would try to open it with MagicISO, which as mentioned stopped working in Windows 8